# JST PH plug and socket compatibility

Tags: connector

How to check compatibility between JST PH plug and socket? Are all connectors from JST with `PH` in name compatible? What about parts with PH suffixed by additional letter like [PHR-2](https://uk.farnell.com/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/phr-2/housing-2way-2mm/dp/3616186)?

For example are [B2B-PH-K-S(LF)(SN)](https://uk.farnell.com/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/b2b-ph-k-s-lf-sn/header-top-entry-2way-2mm/dp/9491856?ost=b2b-ph-k-s%28lf%29%28sn%29) and [PHR-2](https://uk.farnell.com/jst-japan-solderless-terminals/phr-2/housing-2way-2mm/dp/3616186) compatible?

Comment: Hint: Read the datasheets for the receptacle AND the crimp housing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those appear to be compatible.  If the contact housing/plug and header/receptacle both appear on the same datasheet, as these do, it's a pretty safe bet that they are compatible although there are always exceptions.  Some manufacturers have tables of which housings are compatible with which headers, sometimes as a separate document.  Finally, some vendors will have a "compatible products" list but even that is occasionally wrong.